# running cap deploy:cold command gives an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

So i've been trying to deploy my ruby on rails web site with the help of Capistrano and when I run `cap deploy:cold` this is what I get:

```
C:\Sites\blog>cap deploy:cold
  * ←[32m2012-11-02 00:47:49 executing `deploy:cold'←[0m
  * ←[32m2012-11-02 00:47:49 executing `deploy:update'←[0m
 ** transaction: start
  * ←[32m2012-11-02 00:47:49 executing `deploy:update_code'←[0m
    ←[33mexecuting locally: "git ls-remote git@github.com:averageAwesome/blog.gi
t master"←[0m
    ←[2;37mcommand finished in 2686ms←[0m
  * ←[33mexecuting "git clone --depth 1 git@github.com:averageAwesome/blog.git /
var/chroot/home/content/39/10025539/html/blow4849/blog/releases/20121102004752 &
& cd /var/chroot/home/content/39/10025539/html/blow4849/blog/releases/2012110200
4752 && git checkout -b deploy 700dd36e9e5476880fea92c48bffcfb6ff455fe8 && git s
ubmodule init && git submodule sync && export GIT_RECURSIVE=$([ ! \"`git --versi
on`\" \\< \"git version 1.6.5\" ] && echo --recursive) && git submodule update -
-init $GIT_RECURSIVE && rm -Rf  /var/chroot/home/content/39/10025539/html/blow48
49/blog/releases/20121102004752/.git && (echo 700dd36e9e5476880fea92c48bffcfb6ff
455fe8 >  /var/chroot/home/content/39/10025539/html/blow4849/blog/releases/20121
102004752/REVISION)"←[0m
    servers: ["188.121.54.128"]
Password:
    [188.121.54.128] executing command
 ** ←[35m[188.121.54.128 :: out] sh: git: command not found←[0m
    ←[2;37mcommand finished in 164ms←[0m
*** [←[34mdeploy:update_code←[0m] ←[34mrolling back←[0m
  * ←[33mexecuting "rm -rf  /var/chroot/home/content/39/10025539/html/blow4849/b
log/releases/20121102004752; true"←[0m
    servers: ["188.121.54.128"]
    [188.121.54.128] executing command
    ←[2;37mcommand finished in 131ms←[0m
failed: "sh -c 'git clone --depth 1 git@github.com:averageAwesome/blog.git /var/
chroot/home/content/39/10025539/html/blow4849/blog/releases/20121102004752 && cd
 /var/chroot/home/content/39/10025539/html/blow4849/blog/releases/20121102004752
 && git checkout -b deploy 700dd36e9e5476880fea92c48bffcfb6ff455fe8 && git submo
dule init && git submodule sync && export GIT_RECURSIVE=$([ ! \"`git --version`\
" \\< \"git version 1.6.5\" ] && echo --recursive) && git submodule update --ini
t $GIT_RECURSIVE && rm -Rf  /var/chroot/home/content/39/10025539/html/blow4849/b
log/releases/20121102004752/.git && (echo 700dd36e9e5476880fea92c48bffcfb6ff455f
e8 >  /var/chroot/home/content/39/10025539/html/blow4849/blog/releases/201211020
04752/REVISION)'" on 188.121.54.128
```

Any ideas what might be going wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This is the important line:

```
 ** ←[35m[188.121.54.128 :: out] sh: git: command not found←[0m
```

You don't have `git` installed on your deployment server, or if it is, it's not in the deployment user's path.

Comment: i dint have git installed on my deployment server... :)